# Limit of a function tending to Dirac delta

Tags: integration, limits, dirac-delta

I have the following function $$f(t) = \frac{1}{\gamma}e^{-t/\gamma}\left(\frac{t}{\gamma} - \frac{t^2}{2\gamma^2} \right) $$

We have the property that $\int_0^\infty f(t) dt = 0$.  Also, the function has a max at $t_1=\gamma(2-\sqrt{2})$ and a min at $t_2=\gamma(2+\sqrt{2})$.

What I want to show is that when $\gamma\to 0$, the maximum and the minimum becomes two delta functions. Something like, $f(t) \to \delta(t-t_1)- \delta(t-t_2)$ up to some proportionality.

Could someone help with this?

Comment: Distributionally this appears to be zero ...

Comment: ... assuming $e^{t/\gamma}\rightarrow e^{-t/\gamma}$, otherwise $\int_0^\infty f(t)dt$ diverges.

Comment: Thank you, I corrected the minus sign. Could you elaborate on your argument? I would like to understand it better.

Comment: Note that $t_1,t_2\rightarrow 0$ as $\gamma\rightarrow 0$.